# Does the tag order matter?

Tags: support, tags

Is the tag order important in questions?

I have asked a question recently and I put UEFA first, but after it posted, the tournaments became the first tag.

Will the first tags appear on the main site more frequently than the other orders or it's a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 8):

Tags are sorted in order of popularity - see [this Meta.StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/are-the-tags-shown-in-a-particular-order).  They're not based on the order you type them in, or anything like that.